# 128 bit representation and primitives in java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit, 128-bit

I need to represent 128 bit int key in java, like

`0x9c1f03a0d9cf510f2765bd0f226ff5dc`

I know how represent 128 bit variable in theory.. cut into 2 64 bit int or four 32 bit int.

But i need this representation for compare keys (k1 < k2 and k1 == k2) and i dont know how doing that with a key splitted into severals int, and i dont know how split my hexa key into 2 or 4 int either..

I am totally ignorant with bit manipulation and transformation, some explanations would be very useful

Answer (score 2):

Fantastic news! Java provides an arbitrary precision integral type. The [`BigInteger(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-java.lang.String-int-) constructor can be used to take your hex and make a 128-bit value. Further `BigInteger` is `Comparable`. You could use it like,

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("9c1f03a0d9cf510f2765bd0f226ff5dc", 16);
BigInteger bi2 = bi.add(BigInteger.ONE);
if (bi2.compareTo(bi) > 0) {
    System.out.println("Like this");
}
```

Outputs

```
Like this
```

Comment: that is fantastic

Comment: I already know biginteger, but the goal here is to make from scratch.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With [`Long.compareUnsigned`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compareUnsigned-long-long-) (and other methods that treat `long`s as unsigned), bit tricks aren't essential anymore. You can just implement a standard multi-element comparison, where the more-significant values are handled first.

You should use `long`s in preference to `int`s, though, since that will significantly reduce work done by 64-bit CPUs while not having much difference for 32-bit CPUs.

---

For `compareTo` with `long[]`s in little-endian:

```java
public static int keyCompareTo(final long[] a, final long[] b) {
    final int highComp = Long.compareUnsigned(a[1], b[1]);
    if (highComp != 0) return highComp;
    else return Long.compareUnsigned(a[0], b[0]);
}
```

Or, with an object:

```
public class Key implements Comparable<Key> {
    final protected long high;
    final protected long low;

    public int compareTo(final Key other) {
        if (other == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        final int highComp = Long.compareUnsigned(a.high, b.high);
        if (highComp != 0) return highComp;
        else return Long.compareUnsigned(a.low, b.low);
    }
}
```

---

For equality:

```java
a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1]
```

```java
a.high == b.high && a.low == b.low
```

---

For less-than:

```java
final int highComp = Long.compareUnsigned(a[1], b[1]);
final boolean lessThan = highComp < 0 || (highComp == 0 && Long.compareUnsigned(a[0], b[0]) < 0);
```

```java
final int highComp = Long.compareUnsigned(a.high, b.high);
final boolean lessThan = highComp < 0 || (highComp == 0 && Long.compareUnsigned(a.low, b.low) < 0);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i understand how compare two keys now, but, if i can't store a 128 bit key, how can i split it into 2 long ? I dont understand how do that, for split a "T" 32 bit data into two "Thigh" "Tlow" 16 bit its pretty easy : Thigh = T >> 16 and Tlow = T & 0xFFFF. But how with a key like i give in my post ?

Comment: @MasterAI With a hexadecimal `String`, you would leave out the `0x` if it's there and then take 16 characters at a time, using something similar to `high = Long.parseUnsignedLong(str.substring(0, 16), 16); low = Long.parseUnsignedLong(str.substring(16, 16), 16);`. It would need to be adjusted for where the hexadecimal digits start in the string. This is assuming that there are only hexadecimal digits in the `String` with leading zeroes and all. You'd have to adjust it for other formats you want to accept.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,int)).

```
String hexString = "9c1f03a0d9cf510f2765bd0f226ff5dc";
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(hexString, 16);
System.out.println(bigInt);
```

Comment: I already know biginteger, but the goal here is to make from scratch.. Thanks.